# Unhandled Exception Handler in c++

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception

I am working on a C++ library where I want to be able to catch any exceptions that occur that haven't been caught by a try/catch statement.

The only thing I can find while Googling around is a catch(...) block but that wouldn't work, I want the library to catch anything that would normally cause a crash. Like the unhandled exception handler in C#.

It doesn't look like though there is any kind of event handler like this in c++. What I was thinking instead was register a signal handler on things like `SIGSEGV` AND `SIGABRT` and then when I receive the signal, handle the crash.

Is this the best way of doing it or is there any other options for doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: When you say exception, do you mean C++ exception or hardware/OS exceptions (which is a totally different thing)? And a library shouldn't really be setting signal handlers or catch unhandled C++ exceptions, as that's the responsibility of the program itself.

Comment: C++ exceptions, like invalid pointer, or a method throwing an exception but that exception isn't caught by a try/catch block, basically things that if not caught would normally cause the process to crash/core dump. Its a crash monitoring library, so the idea is the library will detect the crash and log it for the user to investigate, hence why the library will be creating the signal handler if that's the only way which it looks like it might be

Comment: Those are the OS/Hardware exceptions. The C++ exceptions are the ones you CAN catch.

Comment: Note about catching the sigsev and sigabort: The program is probably broken irreparably by that point and the [things you can do in a signal handler are greatly restricted](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). It's hard to get so much as a scream for help out and trying to recover and continue execution is all but impossible.

Comment: @user4581301 Yea that's true pointer exceptions etc would be OS issues, so it makes sense I might not be able to get them as you say, if that happens the program is probably totally screwed to get anything useful. But if I could catch non caught exception via a global exception handler would be good. I found the `set_terminate` method but that doesn't look to set it globally when I tried it

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you want to get what you can catch, `int main() {try { code goes here } catch (...) { handler goes here}` will catch it (unless it's in a thread. You'll have to do something similar with the thread's starting function), but since you've bilndly caught everything it's difficult to know what you caught. I'll usually have a cascade of catch blocks from most specific to least  so I have some hope of  knowing what I'm handling before giving up , catching `...` and Logging something like "WTF just happened?"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but not what I'm after, that's something the developer of the main application would need to do. What I'm trying to do is have a library, that as soon as the library is instantiated and initialised with the user API key, the library automatically catches the unhandled exception and logs it without the user needing to do anything specific with their own applications code, although its starting to look like this might not be possible :(

Comment: Like I said, it's generally a bad idea for a library to do. Signal handling should be up to the application using the library. Especially considering that the application might set up signal handlers anyway, either overriding your handlers or you overriding their handler. Signal handling should only be a part of a library if you have an explicit API for the application to use, it should never be done automatically behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to sort of implement this to some degree.

As @user4581301 pointed out I likely wouldn't be able to do anything in the event of a pointer issue or memory issue that might have caused `sigsegv` or a `sigabrt` as if that happens the main app is probably irreversably screwed so wouldn't be able to do anything remotely useful.

However, in the event that an exception is thrown which isn't caught I have found a way to capture it.

When my library initialised I do the following:

```
if (currentTerminationHandler == nullptr)
    {
        currentTerminationHandler = std::get_terminate();
        std::set_terminate(&unhandledTerminateHandler);
    }
```

The unhandledTerminateHandler method then uses the boost stacktrace at https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace.html to return a backtrace that is logged.

Be aware though when doing this when running inside Visual Studio, VS catches the crash before the terminate handler is triggered and stops the terminate trigger from triggering so to get round this you need to run with ctrl+F5 to avoid it running within VS debugger.